# How to pass object to Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like ask you about passing object to Redux.
Below is my code.

```js
// src/actions/writingType.js
export const write = () => ({
    type: 'WRITE',
})

export const update = (obj) => ({

    type: 'UPDATE',
    obj
})
```

```js
// src/reducers/writingType.js
const initialState = {
    writingType: "WRITE",
    obj: null
}

const writingTypeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log('\n inside writingTypeReducer');
    console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'WRITE':
            return {
                ...state,
                writingType: 'WRITE'
            };
        case 'UPDATE':
            return {
                ...state,
                writingType: 'UPDATE',
                obj: action.obj
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default writingTypeReducer;
```

```js
// Contentview.js

import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import MarkdownRenderer from 'react-markdown-renderer';
import './Contentview.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { write, update } from '../../actions/writingType'
import { UserConsumer } from '../../contexts/userContext';
import { Test } from '../../contexts/Test';



const Contentview = (props) => {

    /*
    category: "React"
    contentObj:
        contents: "something"
        createdDatetime: "2019.10.26 08:52:05"
        title: "something"
        wikiIndex: 1
    */
    console.log('\n Contentview');
    console.log(props);
    console.log('\n update(props.contentObj);');
    update(props.contentObj);

    const url = "/editor/" + props.category;
    const updateUrl = "/update/" + props.category;

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="categoryDiv">{props.category}</div>
            <div className="writingDiv"><Link to={url}> A </Link></div>
            <div className="updateDiv"><Link to={updateUrl} > B </Link></div>

            <hr />
            <MarkdownRenderer markdown={props.contentObj.contents} />

        </div>
    );
};

// export default Contentview;

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    writetypestate: state.writingType,
    obj: props.contentObj
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    write: () => dispatch(write()),
    update: (obj) => {
        console.log('Contentview, mapDispatchToProps, update');
        dispatch(update(obj))
    }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Contentview)
```

I used update(props.contentObj); in Contentview.js to pass props.contentObj to Redux and update obj of initialState in src/reducers/writingType.js. But obj of initialState hasn't changed and existed as null.

How should I change code?

Thank you.

Comment: check this things in src/actions/writingType.js put a console.log() inside the write function. if that log is comming which means you are calling the action.

Comment: and in your component level in mapDispatchToProps if you need the object it should be state.obj not props.contentObj. also if you are using combine reducers then put a console.log(state) inside the mapStateToProps

Comment: try the above things let me know any further info or detailed explanation is required

Comment: also in mapStateToProps the second argument is basically the ownProps. so the second argument basically contains whatever props you have passed to this component.

Comment: @  DILEEP THOMAS Thanks, but "put a console.log() inside the write function" made a error.

Comment: export const write = () => {
    console.log('write action calling')
 return {type: 'WRITE'}
}

Comment: try above way, becuase you were trying to return an object direclty so inside if u put a console.log() it will throw error

Comment: @ DILEEP THOMAS Thanks, I tried "export const write = () => { console.log('write action calling') return {type: 'WRITE'} }" and I knew this was called.

Comment: so did u logged the state in mapStateToProps,

Comment: @DILEEP THOMAS Thanks your advice, but I have something that I don't understand. Where exactly should I console.log what? Where How can I log the state in mapStateToProps?

Answer (score 0):

use props.update to call in the main file

```
// Contentview.js

import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import MarkdownRenderer from 'react-markdown-renderer';
import './Contentview.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { write, update } from '../../actions/writingType'
import { UserConsumer } from '../../contexts/userContext';
import { Test } from '../../contexts/Test';



const Contentview = (props) => {

    /*
    category: "React"
    contentObj:
        contents: "something"
        createdDatetime: "2019.10.26 08:52:05"
        title: "something"
        wikiIndex: 1
    */
    console.log('\n Contentview');
    console.log(props);
    console.log('\n update(props.contentObj);');
    props.update(props.contentObj);

    const url = "/editor/" + props.category;
    const updateUrl = "/update/" + props.category;

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="categoryDiv">{props.category}</div>
            <div className="writingDiv"><Link to={url}> A </Link></div>
            <div className="updateDiv"><Link to={updateUrl} > B </Link></div>

            <hr />
            <MarkdownRenderer markdown={props.contentObj.contents} />

        </div>
    );
};

// export default Contentview;

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    writetypestate: state.writingType,
    obj: props.contentObj
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    write: () => dispatch(write()),
    update: (obj) => {
        console.log('Contentview, mapDispatchToProps, update');
        dispatch(update(obj))
    }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Contentview)
```

Please use the above code

Comment: props.update ? can you explain little further in detail, so it will be helpful to understand the problem and the solution

Comment: Thanks, but Could you give me more detail?

Comment: In the file `Contentview.js`, after the console.log statements, where you are calling update(props.contentObj), call props.update(props.contentObj).
Ultimately, our goal is to call the update method from mapDispatchToProps which will be present in props object.